# Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly SQL DW): data type to store SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am using a variable in a stored procedure named `@Stmt nvarchar(4000)` which is holding dynamically generated SQL statement.

In the next step, I am giving an execution call to `dbo.sp_executesql @Stmt;`

However, I am facing syntax issues due to incomplete SQL statement string hold by a variable, whenever characters length is getting over 4000 characters.

What data type should I be using to hold long SQL statements? Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: `nvarchar(MAX)`.